# Streaming ArrayList of POJOs using FasterXML

Tags: java, sockets, fasterxml

I'm currently developing a Napster-like application. I have two static methods that I use for sending information between the client and central server. On any client connect a thread on the server accepts the incoming connection and once connected the client application sends its user data and a list of files described in the ArrayList param passed into this function:

```
/**
 * Send an ArrayList of FileInfo objects to a socket.
 * @param fout Output BufferedWriter
 * @param fileInfoArrayList ArrayList of FileInfo objects to send
 */
public static void sendFileInfoArrayList(BufferedWriter fout, ArrayList<FileInfo> fileInfoArrayList) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
        objectMapper.writeValue(fout, fileInfoArrayList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The server thread uses a similar method to receive information about the recently connected client:

```
/**
 * Receive an ArrayList of FileInfo objects from a socket.
 * @param fin Input BufferedReader
 * @return ArrayList of FileInfo objects received
 */
public static ArrayList<FileInfo> recvFileInfoArrayList(BufferedReader fin) {
    ArrayList<FileInfo> fileInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
        CollectionType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, FileInfo.class);
        fileInfoArrayList = objectMapper.readValue(fin, javaType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileInfoArrayList;
}
```

The next step is the central server thread enters a loop on the condition that the socket connection is maintained waiting to receive a search term from the client. I was intending on just using `BufferedReader.readLine()` on the server and sending the search term `java.lang.String` (with a CRLF appended) using `DataOutputStream.writeBytes()`.

However, when it enters the loop (after the initial exchange of user/fileinfo (which is successful)) `readLine()` just keeps reading `null` over and over. I'm unsure why this is. I need the connection from client to central server to be persistent, hence `objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false)`, so closing it out isn't an option. I've tried `flush()`ing the writer in my static send method above, `shutdownOutput()` on the out `socket`. I can't identify the root of the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: Use a single BufferedReader to read everything. Otherwise, when you tell the first buffered reader to read the JSON, it reads and buffers all the lines that are sent after the JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet I've implemented these suggested changes in my code, tested, and received the same results. I've updated the post, because I agree it's probably better to pass in the BufferedReader than the Socket.